# Compare multi dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, uwp

I have a string array which stores old words and it's corresponding new words.

```
string[,] arrayWords = new string[,] { { "daniel", "dany" }, { "ebrid", "ebraham" }, { "orlang", "lang" }, { "edison", "edwaid" } };
```

Now I want to check each word of input string with this array and need to replace old word with new one. What is the fastest way to check it?

For Example : if `string InputString = "ebrid jackson";`then I want to replace that ebrid with ebraham and need to get the resulted output as "ebraham jackson"

Comment: I strongly recommend to use a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of a `string[,]`.

Comment: How big is the data for which you need to do this? I want to get an idea of how relevant is scaling. In fact I would like to run tests on the appropiate input size. Why? Because sticking to your array will be faster for small data sets, but Dictionary will be faster for large data sets. Also, if you really care about performance: StringBuilder is your friend and Regex is your enemy. Ah, another thing: test, test, test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a string array which stores old words and it's corresponding new words.
>
> ```
> string[,] arrayWords = new string[,] { { "daniel", "dany" }, { "ebrid", "ebraham" }, { "orlang", "lang" }, { "edison", "edwaid" } };
> ```
>
> Now I want to check each word of input string (...)

Therefore, you have an input string (taken from your example):

```
string InputString = "ebrid jackson";
```

In addition, you want to **check each word** of it. Therefore, we start by splitting that string into an enumeration of words. For instance:

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');
```

Then we will check each one for some condition:

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (someCondition(word))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

> (...) with this array (...)

Ah, you are searching. Ok…

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

foreach (var word in words)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayWords.GetLength(0); index++)
    {
        if (word == arrayWords[index, 0])
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, we can do better than that... and [you have already been told so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550016/compare-multi-dimensional-array-in-c-sharp#comment82056573_47550016):

> I strongly recommend to use a Dictionary instead of a string[,].

You can just declare it like this:

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string> { { "daniel", "dany" }, { "ebrid", "ebraham" }, { "orlang", "lang" }, { "edison", "edwaid" } };
```

Alternatively, you can build it from what you have:

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string> ();
 for (int index = 0; index < arrayWords.GetLength(0); index++)
 {
     dictionary[arrayWords[index, 0]] = arrayWords[index, 1];
 }
```

Then search the dictionary:

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This code is not only simpler, but also faster because the dictionary optimizes key access. The time to find a key in the dictionary is constant (`O(1)`)[*] because [it uses a hash table internally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(VS.80).aspx#datastructures20_2_topic6). On the other hand, the time to find a key in the array is linear (`O(N)`) because you have to check item by item. Note that if you had the array sorted, and you were to perform a binary search, that would be `O(log(N))`.

[*]: Except on hash collision, where it is linear.

> and need to replace old word with new one.

Oh, you are replacing. We can do that.

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

var result = new StringBuilder();

var first = true;

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Append(' ');
    }
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        result.Append(dictionary[word]);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Append(word);            
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Output: `ebraham jackson`

I want to mention that using `first` this way will preserve the spaces of the original. Alternatively, you can `Join`:

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        result.Add(dictionary[word]);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(word);            
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

The variation with List is easier to read and maintain. However, it has an extra cost, in that it requires to allocate more strings than using `StringBuilder`.

I guess we can keep going and use everyone's favorite: Linq:

```
var words = InputString.Split(' ');

var result = string.Join(" ", words.Select(word => dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word));
```

Of course, we can combine Linq and StringBuilder:

```
var words = inputString.Split(' ');
var str = words.Aggregate((StringBuilder: new StringBuilder(), First: true), (result, word) =>
{
    if (!result.First)
    {
        result.StringBuilder.Append(" ");
    }
    result.StringBuilder.Append(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
    return (StringBuilder: result.StringBuilder, First: false);
}).ToString();
GC.KeepAlive(str);
```

> What is the fastest way to check it?

Let us consider the alternative to what we have done above...

Well, we could try using good old [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx), but we are trying to match whole words, and `String.Replace` will not do that. However,[`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) would, using word boundaries:

```
foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    InputString = Regex.Replace(InputString, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(pair.Key) + @"\b", pair.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(InputString);
```

Output: `ebraham jackson`

---

I want to note that this alternative code does not do exactly the same thing as the code I posted previously. The difference is that it will replace even what it did replace. That is, if you had a pair `{ "ebraham", "something" }` at the end, this alternative code would yield `something jackson` while the previous one would yield `ebraham jackson` because going word by word it would not replace what it has already replaced.

If we have N words in the input string, and M replacements. On the previous code we would go over `O(N)` words, and for each one get the replacement in `O(log(M))`. Thus, the complexity is `O(N*log(M))`.

On this alternative code, we go over each `O(M)` replacements and for each one we check the whole `O(N)` words to replace. Thus, the complexity is `O(N*M)`.

And `O(N*log(M))` scales better than `O(N*M)`.

---

For mental exercise, let us pretend that we have a method that process a list of any size in 1 minute, and we have another method that does the same job but takes 2 seconds per item. The first method (the one that takes 1 minute) is `O(1)` while the other is `O(N)`. `O(1)` scales better than `O(N)`, yet, if the list you have is 29 items long or less, the second method will be faster. I post this example to show that a better code complexity does not imply faster run time.

---

I wrote some tests I present below. They will execute 13 alternative methods, 100000000 times each. The input is the same as presented in the OP, which means that it neglects scaling.

```
var arrayWords = new[,] { { "daniel", "dany" }, { "ebrid", "ebraham" }, { "orlang", "lang" }, { "edison", "edwaid" } };

var inputString = "ebrid jackson";

Stopwatch sw;

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000; x > 0; x--)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var found = false;
        for (var index = arrayWords.GetLength(0) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (word != arrayWords[index, 0])
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Add(arrayWords[index, 1]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            result.Add(word);
        }
    }
    var str = string.Join(" ", result);
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"array & foreach & List - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000; x > 0; x--)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0, wordsLength = words.Length; i < wordsLength; i++)
    {
        var word = words[i];
        var found = false;
        for (var index = arrayWords.GetLength(0) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (word != arrayWords[index, 0])
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Add(arrayWords[index, 1]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            result.Add(word);
        }
    }

    var str = string.Join(" ", result);
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"array & for & List - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000; x > 0; x--)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    var first = true;

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(" ");
        }
        var found = false;
        for (var index = arrayWords.GetLength(0) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (word != arrayWords[index, 0])
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Append(arrayWords[index, 1]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            result.Append(word);
        }
    }
    var str = result.ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"array & foreach & StringBuilder - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000; x > 0; x--)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    var first = true;

    for (int i = 0, wordsLength = words.Length; i < wordsLength; i++)
    {
        var word = words[i];
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(" ");
        }
        var found = false;
        for (var index = arrayWords.GetLength(0) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (word != arrayWords[index, 0])
            {
                continue;
            }
            result.Append(arrayWords[index, 1]);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            result.Append(word);
        }
    }

    var str = result.ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000; x > 0; x--)
{
    var str = inputString;
    for (var index = arrayWords.GetLength(0) - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(arrayWords[index, 0]) + @"\b", arrayWords[index, 1]);
    }
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"array & Regex - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

// Notice I am not cointing the time to build the Dictionary
// I decided this because I suppose it is possible you get
// the input into the Dictionary directly,
// And if you cannot, then this should be fast anyway
// Run your own tests if you disagree.

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (var index = 0; index < arrayWords.GetLength(0); index++)
{
    dictionary[arrayWords[index, 0]] = arrayWords[index, 1];
}

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        result.Add(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
    }
    var str = string.Join(" ", result);
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & foreach & List - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0, wordsLength = words.Length; i < wordsLength; i++)
    {
        var word = words[i];
        result.Add(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
    }

    var str = string.Join(" ", result);
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & for & List - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');
    var str = string.Join(" ", words.Select(word => dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word));
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & Linq - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    var first = true;

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(" ");
        }
        result.Append(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
    }
    var str = result.ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & foreach & StringBuilder - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');

    var result = new StringBuilder();

    var first = true;

    for (int i = 0, wordsLength = words.Length; i < wordsLength; i++)
    {
        var word = words[i];
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(" ");
        }
        result.Append(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
    }

    var str = result.ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
{
    var words = inputString.Split(' ');
    var str = words.Aggregate((StringBuilder: new StringBuilder(), First: true), (result, word) =>
    {
        if (!result.First)
        {
            result.StringBuilder.Append(" ");
        }
        result.StringBuilder.Append(dictionary.ContainsKey(word) ? dictionary[word] : word);
        return (StringBuilder: result.StringBuilder, First: false);
    }).ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & Linq & StringBuilder - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000 - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    var str = inputString;
    foreach (var pair in dictionary)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(pair.Key) + @"\b", pair.Value);
    }
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & foreach & Regex - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var x = 100000000 - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    var str = dictionary.Aggregate(inputString, (current, pair) => Regex.Replace(current, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(pair.Key) + @"\b", pair.Value));
    GC.KeepAlive(str);
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary & Linq & Regex - Time taken: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

/*----------------------------------*/
```

Output:

```
array & foreach & List - Time taken: 28987.198ms
array & for & List - Time taken: 27749.3735ms
array & foreach & StringBuilder - Time taken: 18953.0578ms
array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 18682.1843ms
array & Regex - Time taken: 224451.3549ms
Dictionary & foreach & List - Time taken: 30875.7747ms
Dictionary & for & List - Time taken: 31131.463ms
Dictionary & Linq - Time taken: 30594.4158ms
Dictionary & foreach & StringBuilder - Time taken: 22467.4147ms
Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 21804.911ms
Dictionary & Linq & StringBuilder - Time taken: 39030.8662ms
Dictionary & foreach & Regex - Time taken: 233443.6416ms
Dictionary & Linq & Regex - Time taken: 245098.4077ms
```

You can see there - if you opt to believe my results - StringBuilder is the way to go.

---

Going back to the scaling problem, I tood the faster version that uses array and the faster that uses Dictionary and tested them with four different inputs, each one larger than the previous.

I am not posting the code here because it goes over the maximun size of an answer on this site. In fact, every thing that claim to run C# online that I was able to test ends up with a timeout... so [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L5DbsEuz). In fact, I ended up using 100 times less iterations because the large data set was taking too long.

The sizes of the data for this test were:

```
initial: 4 matches, 2 words
small: 8 matches, 6 words
medium: 32 matches, 14 words
large: 256 matches, 57 words
```

Output:

```
initial
array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 191.7385ms
Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 215.2904ms
small
array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 622.6672ms
Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 664.1003ms
medium
array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 2393.254ms
Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 1353.2854ms
large
array & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 47555.9804ms
Dictionary & for & StringBuilder - Time taken: 6548.9997ms
```

As you can see, using array is faster for the initial and small data sets, but from there on Dictionary is faster.

---

Specifications for the tests:

- Microsoft Windows 10 64 bits - version: 1709 - build 16299.64
- Intel Core i3 6100 - Skylake - 3.70GHz
- 8GB RAM
- .NET version 4.0.30319.42000 (v4.6)
- Code tested on LinqPad 5 Free Edition (v5.26.01) – with optimization on

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[,] arrayWords = new string[,] { { "daniel", "dany" }, { "ebrid", "ebraham" }, { "orlang", "lang" }, { "edison", "edwaid" } };

    string inputName = "ebrid jackson";
    // get name only
    string name = inputName.Split(' ')[0];


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayWords.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        if(arrayWords[i,0] == name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New name " + name + " " + arrayWords[i,1]);
        }
    }
```